# How to know if this differential equation has a non-trivial solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I've tried solving the following (diffusion) equation numerically ($\alpha$ is const)

$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{T^{1/2}}\frac{dT}{dx}\right)+\alpha T^{3/2}=0$$

since it has no analytic solution. The BC's are $T(1)=0$ and $T'(0)=0$. The numerical solution points out to $T(x)=0$ as the solution.

I also tried an equivalent solution by setting $V=T^{1/2}$:

$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{dV}{dx}\right)+\frac{\alpha}{2}V^3=0,$$

but I'm also getting $V(x)=0$.

The problem is that I'm quite convinced that this has other solution than the trivial one (basically by physical arguments).

Is there any way of prooving that another solution exists besides the trivial one?

NOTE: I've seen in a book the author assuming a certain profie for $T(x)$ with some free parameters, and then taking the first moments of the equation to get those free parameters. I am not however very confident with that approach.

Comment: What are the domains of $T$ and $V$?

Comment: Yeah, also please specify boundary conditions

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to add that! I've already edited the question. The domain is $x\in[0,1]$

Comment: We know that $T\equiv 0$ is a solution. You can use the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) to prove the (eventual) uniqueness of the solution to this ODE. If the conditions of the theorem hold, the trivial solution is unique; otherwise, the uniqueness cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: You have a division by zero in your equation. Numerical techniques do not like that. Can you comment on what numerical technique you have tried and how you handled the 1/x terms?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins, instead of using $T'(0)=0$, I used $T'(0.0001)=0$. Would you say it's not a good idea?

Comment: I think a better solution to the problem raised by @AleksejsFomins is to expand the derivative term using the product rule and than multiplying the equation by $x$, $T^{-3/2}$, etc. until you get rid of singularities.

Comment: @rafa11111 I think that even using that, the problem of singularities would appear, at least if you're using a method like RK, where the equation should be organized like $dT/dx=f(x,T)$, and that $f$-function would have such singularities.

Comment: Maybe, one should evaluate the manipulations and see what happens. But I don't think a Runge-Kutta-like method is suitable here, I would rather use a finite differences approach (unless you are using the shooting method). Anyway, I think that the singularities are only found at the boundary of the domain. Naturally, the equation should not be solved in the boundaries, in which the boundary conditions are applied. Also, close to the boundaries you can change the discretization to avoid a singularity in the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the problem given by
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( x k(T) \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \right) + f(T)
$$
$$
T = T_0(x), \ \ \ t=0
$$
$$
\frac{dT}{dx} = 0, \ \ \ x=0
$$
$$
T = 0, \ \ \ x=1
$$

This problem describes the transient heat transfer along the radial direction of an infinitely long cylinder of radius $1$. The surface of that cylinder is kept at temperature $0$. Imagine initially that there is no heat generation (i.e., $f(T) = 0$). In that case, since the surface temperature cannot change, the cylinder will lose heat to the region surrounding the cylinder until the temperature of the cylinder is also $0$ (which should normally take an infinite amount of time). Therefore, the steady-state solution (corresponding to the case with $\partial T/\partial t = 0$) will be $T=0$.

However, if there is heat generation ($f(T)\neq 0$) and the initial temperature profile $T_0(x)$ is nonzero, the cylinder could keep itself heated if "enough" heat is generated. Therefore, even losing heat to the ambient the cylinder would still have a nonzero temperature distribution due to the heat source, which itself depends on the temperature. Naturally, if $f(0)=0$ and the initial temperature profile is $T_0(x)=0$, the cylinder will not be able to heat itself and the solution will be $T=0$ for all $t>0$ and $0<x<1$.

In your case, $k(T) = T^{-1/2}$ and $f(T)=\alpha T^{3/2}$, which corresponds to the case with $f(0)=0$. Therefore, in the alternative problem of transient heat conduction, the steady-state solution can depend on the initial profile. A numerical approach to this issue could involve the solution of the transient PDE instead of the steady-state ODE and verify the dependence of the steady-state solution on the initial profile. That kind of PDE is usually *not* more difficult to solve than some ODE's. Take a look at the FTCS or Crank-Nicholson schemes.

I previously commented about using the Picard-Lindelöf theorem to study the uniqueness of the solution of your problem. Later I noticed that your problem is a boundary value problem, and not a initial value problem (which is the kind of problem to which the theorem applies). Therefore, a rigorous mathematical study of the uniqueness of the solution will be more complicated.

Comment: Indeed, that was the initial problem with a transient term, and because I suspected a steady-state solution would exist, I decided to remove the $\partial_t$ term. Why is it possible that with the transient term the equation evolves to a non-trivial stationary solution, whereas wihout the transient term no such thing occurs?

Comment: From a mathematical point of view, I would say that the theory of PDE's is more convoluted than the theory of ODE's. The conditions of existence and unicity for PDE's can be totally different than the conditions for ODE's (disclaimer: I'm an engineer, not a mathematician). In other words, your steady-state problem is a _degenerate_ case of the original, transient, problem. In a "common" situation you would not lose much information by eliminating the $\partial T/\partial t$ term. In that case, however, the elimination of the time dependence prevents you from obtaining the non-trivial solution.

Comment: @AJHC As I discussed in the answer, you need to have $T_0(x)\neq 0$ to have a nontrivial solution. If you have a steady-state problem, you cannot "warn" the problem that the initial condition was nontrivial, then the problem cannot know whether the trivial solution is physically suitable or not. It's related to the fact that the transient problem is _parabolic_. Summarizing, you have nontrivial solutions (I guess), but your method is not able to reach them.